# c# Entity Framework - Insert Data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and try to save data into my database but my code does nothing.

```
public SoullutionEntities db = new SoullutionEntities();
Answers answers = new Answers();
answers.questionID = 1;
answers.answer = "yes";
db.Answers.Add(answers);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Answers** class:

```
namespace MMPI2_Test.Model { 
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 

    public partial class Answers { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string answer { get; set; } 
        public int questionID { get; set; } 
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you show me the  model class of Answers ? 
and are sure that questionID is not auto generated by database

Comment: namespace MMPI2_Test.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Answers
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string answer{ get; set; }
        public int questionID{ get; set; }
    
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: do you get any error while running this code?

Comment: no, it runs perfectly during debugging

Comment: my code still is doing nothing

Comment: What value do you get in `answers.Id` after `SaveChanges`?

Comment: the value is null